# How do I create .cur and .ani custom cursors for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, icons, mouse-cursor

I am trying to figure out how to make custom mouse cursors for Windows 7.

I understand that the preferred file format is in .ani and .cur - however I have yet to find a legitimate program that will create these files.  At the moment, I am able to create mouse icons using GIMP and saving as .ico files (its a bit finicky and I can't select the "hot spot" where the actually click occurs) - but I would like to work up to having actually animated icons as well.  I see somewhere online that GIMP at one point had a plugin for .cur and .ani files but I haven't seen it when I attempt to look through GIMP's plugin library.

I have looked into working with Photoshop since I heard its good about creating cursor icons, and I feel I can trust Adobe to not give me viruses.

Any thoughts or suggestions?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the .cur and .ani files.
Paint.NET alongside a particular plugin that was made by one of the users allow people to save files as .cur files and even select the hotspot!  Haven't figured out how to make .ani files yet, but the plugin does allow you to make them.